# How can i only fetch data without status?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to create a todo-list and I have a problem. When I create a new task and move back to display the list, I see an empty field and created task. I discovered that this empty field is the status that the server sends after creating the task. There is a way that this field will not be displayed ?

```
export const fetchtodos = () => async dispatch => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const response = await todosApi.get('/todos', {
    headers: { Authorization: token }
  });
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_TODOS, payload: response.data });
};
```

Here is a list component:

```
  todosList() {
return this.props.todos.map(function(currentTodo, i) {
  return <TodosList todo={currentTodo} key={i} />;
});
```

}

```
 const TodosList = props => (
  <tr>
    <td className={props.todo.completed ? "completed" : "TableText"}>
      <div className="TodoTableContent">
        <Link to={"/edit/" + props.todo._id} className="TodoLinkContent">
          {props.todo.title}
        </Link>
        <Link to={"/delete/" + props.todo._id} className="a_edit">
          <img src={Trash} alt="Usuń" className="Deletefavicon" />
        </Link>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
);
```

I expected that the created task will be displayed. but status from server is also displayed as undentifined 
[unexpected result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNgZb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render the component only if todo is not undefined:

```
{ props.todo && (
  <Link to={"/edit/" + props.todo._id} className="TodoLinkContent">
    {props.todo.title}
  </Link>
  <Link to={"/delete/" + props.todo._id} className="a_edit">
    <img src={Trash} alt="Usuń" className="Deletefavicon" />
  </Link> )
}
```